# Getting the best performance out of {fmt}

Tags: c++, fmt

I need to format a FILETIME value info a wide string buffer and configuration provides the format string.

What I am actually doing:

- Config provides the format string: `L"{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}.{mmm}"`
- Convert the FILETIME to System time:

```
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&fileTime, &stUTC);
```

- Format the string with

```
    fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(buffer), strFormat,        
             fmt::arg(L"YYYY", stUTC.wYear),
             fmt::arg(L"MM", stUTC.wMonth),
             fmt::arg(L"DD", stUTC.wDay),
             fmt::arg(L"hh", stUTC.wHour),
             fmt::arg(L"mm", stUTC.wMinute),
             fmt::arg(L"ss", stUTC.wSecond),
             fmt::arg(L"mmm", stUTC.wMilliseconds));
```

I perfectly understand that with a service comes a cost :) but my code is calling this statement millions of time and the performance penalty is clearly present (more than 6% of CPU usage).

"Anything" I could do to improve this code would be welcomed.

I saw that {fmt} has a [time API support](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#time-api).
Unfortunately, it seems to be unable to format the millisecond part of the time/date and, it requires some conversion effort from `FILETIME` to `std::time_t`...

Should I forget about the "custom" format string and provide a custom formatter for the `FILETIME` (or `SYSTEMTIME`) types? Would that result in a significant performance boost?

I'd appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Comment: If I was deeply concerned about performance, I would not use any generic formatting tools like this.  Instead I would look at processing the custom format string into a simple state machine with inputs driven by offsets into the SYSTEMTIME struct, and string lookup tables for all the 2-, 3- and 4-digit zero-padded unsigned values.  Another small optimization for frequent log entries is to avoid converting the time if it's identical to the previous time.

Comment: If your logging routine shows up in your performance graphs, you are usually missunderstanding the graph, or doing something wrong. Could you post the code?

Comment: Times are extracted from file system meta data and are in the millions.
So, I cannot predict their values (and are not related to current time).
This is not a logging routine but a file system meta data dump tool into a csv. 

I like your state machine idea though.

Comment: I have added an answer with some more specific detail about how I would go about this.  In the answer, I point out it's not really a state machine.  Well, I suppose it technically is, but it's pretty much the simplest state machine ever.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tried using fmt's constexpr format string parser? (to enable it follow the instructions in the docs about enabling compile-time detection of invalid argument types)

Comment: How many times per second do you get or need to get? If your application/thread is just a `while(true){ FormatDate(); }` then one core will be busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments I suggested parsing your custom time format string into a simple state machine.  It does not even have to be a state machine as such.  It is simply a linear series of instructions.

Currently, the `fmt` class needs to do a bit of work to parse the format type and then convert an integer to a zero-padded string.  It is possible, though unlikely, that it is as heavily optimized as I'm about to suggest.

The basic idea is to have a (large) lookup table, which of course can be generated at runtime, but for the purposes of quick illustration:

```
const wchar_t zeroPad4[10000][5] = { L"0000", L"0001", L"0002", ..., L"9999" };
```

You can have 1-, 2- and 3-digit lookup tables if you want, or alternatively recognize that these values are all contained in the 4-digit lookup table if you just add an offset.

So to output a number, you just need to know what the offset in `SYSTEMTIME` is, what type the value is, and what string offset to apply (0 for 4-digit, 1 for 3-digit, etc).  It makes things simpler, given that all struct elements in `SYSTEMTIME` are the same type.  And you should reasonably assume that no values require range checks, although you can add that if unsure.

And you can configure it like this:

```
struct Output {
    int dataOffset;  // offset into SYSTEMTIME struct
    int count;       // extra adjustment after string lookup
};
```

What about literal strings?  Well, you can either copy those or just repurpose `Output` to use a negative `dataOffset` representing where to start in the format string and `count` to hold how many characters to output in that mode.  If you need extra output modes, extend this struct with a `mode` member.

Anwyay, let's take your string `L"{YYYY}-{MM}-{DD} {hh}:{mm}:{ss}.{mmm}"` as an example.  After you parse this, you would end up with:

```
Output outputs[] {
    { offsetof(SYSTEMTIME, wYear), 0 },         // "{YYYY}"
    { -6, 1 },                                  // "-"
    { offsetof(SYSTEMTIME, wMonth), 2 },        // "{MM}"
    { -11, 1 },                                 // "-"
    { offsetof(SYSTEMTIME, wDay), 2 },          // "{DD}"
    { -16, 1 },                                 // " "
    // etc...  you get the idea
    { offsetof(SYSTEMTIME, wMilliseconds), 1 }, // "{mmm}"
    { -1, 0 },                                  // terminate
};
```

It shouldn't take much to see that, when you have a `SYSTEMTIME` as input, a pointer to the original format string, the lookup table, and this basic array of instructions you can go ahead and output the result into a pre-sized buffer very quickly.

I'm sure you can come up with the code to execute these instructions efficiently.

The main drawback of this approach is the size of the lookup table may lead to cache issues.  However, most lookups will occur in the first 100 elements.  You could also compress the table to ordinary `char` values and then inject the `wchar_t` zero bytes when copying.

As always: experiment, measure, and have fun!

Comment: I will certainly have a look and experiment something like that.

I'll report back after some testing. 

Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, and please come back and let us know what performance gains (if any) you got from it.